# How to color(background) excel cell using conditions using python and write the same colored sheet back to excel?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter, xlwt

### Hi I have excel sheet named 'master'

```
Start       Customer    Country Parent group                Issue
2           Jaguar      USA     TATA                        HW
3           Suzuki      Japan   Suzuki Motors               HW
6           GM          USA     General Motors              SW
7           Hyundai     Japan   Hyundai Motrs               HW
8           Google      USA     Google corporations         SW
12          TCS         India   TATA Consultancy Services   HW
14          Jaguar      USA     TATA                        HW
19          AT & T      USA     AT & T Corporation          SW
28          Oracle      USA     Oracle Services             SW
30          Benz        Germany Mercedez Benz               SW
31          Suzuki      Japan   Suzuki Motors               SW
49          Honda       Japan   HONDA motors                HW
90          GM          USA     General Motors              SW
91          Hyundai     Japan   Hyundai motors              HW
96          Jaguar      USA     TATA                        SW
98          Suzuki      Japan   Suzuki Motors               HW
100         TCS         India   TATA Consultancy Services   HW
114         Hyundai     Japan   Hyundai motors              HW
119         AT & T      USA     AT & T Corporation          SW
125         Suzuki      Japan   Suzuki Motors               SW
```

where I want to colour cells of customer column where customer is Honda, TCS, Jaguar and Suzuki using for loop over list of these four customers.
List = ['Honda', 'TCS', 'Jaguar', 'Suzuki']

and write colored data frame in excel sheet

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked in to conditional formatting?

Comment: I am unable to do anything.....I want to colour cells of customer column to yellow using any python package and write that to excel sheet.

Comment: Where's your own code?

Comment: Is there any other way using different package? StyleFrame takes lot of time. I want to color only cells with Honda, TCS, Jaguar and Suzuki only....

Comment: @NikhilMangire How many rows and columns there are in the file?

Comment: @DeepSpace no of columns would remain same but no of rows would be different each time

Comment: @NikhilMangire A ballpark? you said it was slow. How many rows the file you tried it with had?

Comment: @DeepSpace actually it colors cells as per requirement, but it changes format of each cell, like cell content gets shrinked and font also, changes. does StyleFrame has provision to set cell formats?

Comment: @NikhilMangire yes, it does. You can see everything that `Styler` supports here: http://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_documentation.html#styler-class
Also, if you want to retain the styling of the sheet you can pass `read_style=True` to `read_excel`: http://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_documentation.html#read-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged this question with `StyleFrame` so I suppose you want a solution using it.

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('path/to/excel.xlsx', sheetname='master')

yellow_bg = Styler(bg_color='yellow')

sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['Customer'].isin(('Honda', 'TCS', 'Jaguar', 'Suzuki'))],
                          styler_obj=yellow_bg,
                          cols_to_style='Customer')

sf.to_excel('path/to/excel.xlsx').save()
```

You may provide `sheet_name` (note underscore) to `to_excel` if you don't want to use Excel's default sheet name ('Sheet1')